# Data column against all data tables on a schema

Tags: mysql

Our databases are controlled by a third-party. As a result, a lot of the time we are searching for data ourselves as there is no schema or documentation for this.

We have located the data column that we require as `OPSREF$$`. We need to find this against all data tables on a schema. What would be the best MySQL query to retrieve this data?.

Answer (score 0):

You can find lots of information about your databases in information_schema - assuming you have access to it.

```
select table_schema,table_name,column_name from information_schema.columns where column_name = 'OPSREF$$'
```